# How to draw multiple rectangles based on input values?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a little form where I can put in different values and draw two rectangles with the rectangle selected from the dropdown centered inside the rectangle drawn with the values from the free text fields.

The first rectangle coming from the free text fields will draw, but only if the code to draw the second rectangle from the dropdown box is stripped out. I thought it would be easiest to use a switch statement to draw the second rectangle, but not sure if it should be placed within the same function. I'm pretty new to JS, so I don't know the best thing to do.

```js
function updateForm(width, height, box) {
     "use strict";
     var x = 50;
     var y = 50;
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //Create a canvas 
     //Set canvas width/height
     canvas.style.width = "100%";
     canvas.style.height = "100%";
     // Set canvas drawing area width/height
     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
     //Position canvas
     canvas.style.position = "absolute";
     canvas.style.left = 0;
     canvas.style.top = 350;
     canvas.style.zIndex = 100000;
     canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none"; 
     document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     //Draw rectangle
     context.rect(x, y, height*50, width*50);
     context.fillStyle = "blue";
     context.fill();
       switch (box) {
        case 'three-two': 
          context.rect(x, y, 150,200);
          context.fillStyle = "green";
          context.fill();
        break;
        case 'four-six': 
          context.rect(x, y, 200,300);
          context.fillStyle = "red";
          context.fill();
        break;
        case 'five-four': 
          context.rect(x, y, 250,200);
          context.fillStyle = "orange";
          context.fill();
        break;
        default:
        alert("The value supplied is out of range!");
        break;
        }
     }

    function draw() {
    var width = document.getElementById("wid").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
    var box = document.getElementById("boxSize").value;
    updateForm(width, height, box);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form id="areaform">
    <label for="wid">Width:</label>
    <input id="wid" type="number">
    <label for="hgt">Length:</label>
    <input id="hgt" type="number">
    <label for="boxSize">Box Size</label>
    <select id="boxSize" name="boxSize">
      <option value="three-two">3x2</option>
      <option value="four-six">4x6</option>
      <option value="five-four">5x4</option>

    </select>

    <button onclick="draw()" type="button">Draw Rectangle</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

With all of the code above, neither rectangle will render. I want two rectangles to render with the first based on numeric values from the width/height fields and the second to render on top of and centered in the first rectangle based on my dimensions matched to the chosen value from the dropdown box.

Comment: Can you create a demo? Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: @Albondi Just added a demo! I tried the debugger but it just said 'undefined' and nothing more (possible I did not do it right)

Comment: Your demo has a very simple mistake.. part of your comment on line 5 is all by itself on line 6 and this is causing "element is not defined" I don't think you are ready to ask a question yet. I am afraid this question is going to get down votes. Try to find some tutorials on javascript and practice coding and you will be able to ask a better quality question.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- There is a comment that has a newline in it, putting `element` on a separate line. That causes an error
- `draw` is a local function, so it cannot be referenced from HTML. It should be a global function.
- Your squares are getting the last applied fill color. You need to start each new rectangle with `context.beginPath()` to avoid this.
- width and height are supplied in the inverse order

Then, as you want to center the second rectangle, you should calculate what the appropriate x and y coordinates should be based on the size of both rectangles.

Here is your code with those corrections:

```js
function updateForm(width, height, box) {
     "use strict";
     var x = 50;
     var y = 50;
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //Create a canvas element
     //Set canvas width/height
     canvas.style.width = "100%";
     canvas.style.height = "100%";
     // Set canvas drawing area width/height
     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
     //Position canvas
     canvas.style.position = "absolute";
     canvas.style.left = 0;
     canvas.style.top = 350;
     canvas.style.zIndex = 100000;
     canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none"; 
     document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     //Draw rectangle
     context.beginPath();
     context.fillStyle = "blue";
     console.log('----------------');
     console.log(x, y, width*50, height*50);
     context.rect(x, y, width*50, height*50);
     context.fill();
     context.beginPath();
       switch (box) {
        case 'three-two':
          console.log(x+(width-3)*25, y+(height-4)*25, 150, 200);
          context.rect(x+(width-3)*25, y+(height-4)*25, 150, 200);
          context.fillStyle = "green";
        break;
        case 'four-six': 
          context.rect(x+(width-4)*25, y+(height-6)*25, 200, 300);
          context.fillStyle = "red";
        break;
        case 'five-four': 
          context.rect(x+(width-5)*25, y+(height-4)*25, 250, 200);
          context.fillStyle = "orange";
        break;
     }
     context.fill();
}

function draw() {
    var width = document.getElementById("wid").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
    var box = document.getElementById("boxSize").value;
    updateForm(width, height, box);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="areaform">
    <label for="wid">Width:</label>
    <input id="wid" type="number">
    <label for="hgt">Length:</label>
    <input id="hgt" type="number">
    <label for="boxSize">Box Size</label>
    <select id="boxSize" name="boxSize">
      <option value="three-two">3x2</option>
      <option value="four-six">4x6</option>
      <option value="five-four">5x4</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="draw()" type="button">Draw Rectangle</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I did not touch the mechanism you have used to generate a new canvas for every time the user clicks the button, each canvas overlaying the previous one. Be aware that the canvas background is transparent, so that you could potentially still see parts of a previously generated pair of rectangles appear next to the newer ones.

If you don't want that to happen, then just create one canvas element in the static HTML, and don't generate it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the z-index of the canvas is the same for each rectangle.
Try moving that inside your switch/case construct with values like 3000, 2000, 1000.

```js
function updateForm(width, height, box) {
     "use strict";
     var x = 50;
     var y = 50;
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); //Create a canvas 
     //Set canvas width/height
     canvas.style.width = "100%";
     canvas.style.height = "100%";
     // Set canvas drawing area width/height
     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
     //Position canvas
     canvas.style.position = "absolute";
     canvas.style.left = 0;
     canvas.style.top = 350;
     canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none"; 
     document.body.appendChild(canvas); //Append canvas to body element
     var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
     //Draw rectangle
     context.rect(x, y, height*50, width*50);
     context.fillStyle = "blue";
     context.fill();
       switch (box) {
        case 'three-two': 
          canvas.style.zIndex = 3000;
          context.rect(x, y, 150,200);
          context.fillStyle = "green";
          context.fill();
        break;
        case 'four-six': 
          canvas.style.zIndex = 2000;
          context.rect(x, y, 200,300);
          context.fillStyle = "red";
          context.fill();
        break;
        case 'five-four': 
          canvas.style.zIndex = 1000;
          context.rect(x, y, 250,200);
          context.fillStyle = "orange";
          context.fill();
        break;
        default:
        alert("The value supplied is out of range!");
        break;
        }
     }

    function draw() {
    var width = document.getElementById("wid").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
    var box = document.getElementById("boxSize").value;
    updateForm(width, height, box);
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form id="areaform">
    <label for="wid">Width:</label>
    <input id="wid" type="number">
    <label for="hgt">Length:</label>
    <input id="hgt" type="number">
    <label for="boxSize">Box Size</label>
    <select id="boxSize" name="boxSize">
      <option value="three-two">3x2</option>
      <option value="four-six">4x6</option>
      <option value="five-four">5x4</option>

    </select>

    <button onclick="draw()" type="button">Draw Rectangle</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```